# Conditionally concat jinja2 lists

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Some data used in an ansible role:

```
list1:
  - foo
  - bar
list2:             # sometimes this is empty
```

This ansible task fails:

```
- name: hello
  somemodule:
    dosomething: "{{ list1 + list2 }}"
```

Error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{list1 + list2}}): can only concatenate list (not \"NoneType\") to list"}

Is there a way to conditionally concatenate only if `list2` is not empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`none`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#none) bulitin test combined with an [inline if expression](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#if-expression) for this:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ list1 + (list2 if list2 is not none else []) }}"
```

Given the playbook

```
- hosts: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    list1:
      - foo
      - bar
    list2:

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list1 + (list2 if list2 is not none else [])  }}"
```

A play will result in this recap:

```
PLAY [local] **************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "msg": [
        "foo",
        "bar"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************
local                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: This will not work unless `list2` is totally undefined. With current OP's example, it will still fire an error. You need to either totally remove the declaration, or to make it an empty list (i.e. `list2: []`)

Comment: Yep my bad I though undefined would catch that. I have an edit coming

Comment: Happens to the best ;)

Comment: Well, although your edit is technically absolutely correct, I would still strongly encourage OP to use `default` without declaring the list, and to verbosely declare empty lists as.... empty lists and not as none/empty strings.

Comment: @Zeitounator The nice thing about your approach of `list2: []` is that the above conditional check becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this right now.  The way I handle it is to use the default() Jinja2 filter: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default

```yaml
- name: Concatenate list1, list2 if they exist
  debug:
    msg: "{{ (list1 | default([])) + (list2 | default([])) }}"
```

This concatenates list1 and list2 if either exists, otherwise a zero-element list is used.

Specifically, I'm using this to recursively populate an empty list: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html#id9

```yaml
- name: recursively populate list, concatenating each element with string
  set_fact:
    new_list: "{{ (new_list | default([])) | union(['Mystring' + item]) }}"
    loop: orig_list
```

In this case, new_list doesn't exist until after the first loop iteration, so a default empty list is needed for the first pass.  It's not the most obvious thing, but it's in the official Ansible docs, so may as well use it!